# Change the theme of one page without changing menu, search bar... in WordPress

Tags: css, wordpress, themes

Is there any way to use a theme **only** for the contents of one page?

I have already tried *Multiple Themes* plugin but it changes the appeareance of the whole html document (menu, search bar,... also)

[image]

Comment: add `page-your-page-slug.php` to your current theme. Copy code from `page.php` and do customization. `your-page-slug` can be replace by 'page id' like: `page-123.php`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can.

**1.Change the Content Structure.**

To change the content structure, you need to create a custom page template.
You can follow this article to know more about how to add a custom page template to your theme and assign it to your page.
http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-themes/how-to-create-a-custom-page-in-wordpress/

**2.Only Change the Style**

If the theme do it right, there should be a specific css class for the page on the HTML body tag. For example, page-id-1234. So all you need is add the css with the class for the page.

```
.page-id-1234 #entry-content {
    //some css for the page
 }
```